# get attachment by its name/url instant of id?

Tags: wordpress, attachment

How get attachment by its name/url instant of id

```
function wpa_attachment_link( $link, $id ){
    return home_url() . '/?attachment_id=' . $id;
}
add_filter( 'attachment_link', 'wpa_attachment_link', 10, 2 );
```

Answer (score 1):

Try `attachment_url_to_postid()`, see here:
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/attachment_url_to_postid/

This will get you the attachment ID, that you can then use with `wp_get_attachment_image()` and `wp_get_attachment_metadata()`